# create new SQLalchemy object fails when referenceing uid

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

New python and SQLAlchemy user here (yeah i know :)) anyway, I am trying to create some tables using a user, sensor, and reading table where both user and sensor have a one to many relationship to a reading.

My classes are like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    uid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    firstName = db.Column(db.String(100))
    lastName = db.Column(db.String(100))
    emailAddress = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, index=True)
    pwHash = db.Column(db.String(256))
    userLevel = db.Column(db.Integer())
    userAccountType = db.Column(db.Integer())
    isUserActive = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    isUserLockedOut = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    userLastLogin = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    lastInvalidLogin = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    userCreatedAt = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    userConfirmedAt = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    userUpdatedAt = db.Column(db.DateTime(), onupdate=datetime.datetime.now())
    userAddress = db.relationship('Address', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    userContactMethod = db.relationship('UserContactMethod', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    userSensor = db.relationship('Sensor', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    userReading = db.relationship('Reading', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    deliveryEvents = db.relationship('logSMTPDeliveryEvents', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')


class Reading(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'reading'

    rid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.uid'))
    sid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sensor.sid'))
    readingTimestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    readingLightValue = db.Column(db.Integer)
    readingLightStatus = db.Column(db.String(6))
    readingTemp1 = db.Column(db.Float)
    readingTemp2 = db.Column(db.Float)
    readingHumidity = db.Column(db.Float)

    def __init__(self, uid, sid, readingTimestamp, readingLightValue, readingLightStatus, readingTemp1, readingTemp2,
                 readingHumidity):

        self.uid = uid
        self.sid = sid
        self.readingTimestamp = readingTimestamp
        self.readingLightValue = readingLightValue
        self.readingLightStatus = readingLightStatus
        self.readingTemp1 = readingTemp1
        self.readingTemp2 = readingTemp2
        self.readingHumidity = readingHumidity
```

So, if I try and create on object like this:

```
    newReading = Reading(uid=10, sid=123,readingTimestamp = readingTimestamp, readingLightValue=readingLightValue,
                         readingLightStatus=readingLightStatus, readingTemp1=readingTemp1, readingTemp2=readingTemp2,
                         readingHumidity=readingHumidity)
    db.session.add(newReading)
    db.session.commit()
```

Where I hardcode the uid everything works fine.  Hoewever if I try and use my query before that like so:

```
    userID = db.session.query(User.uid).filter(User.emailAddress == userEmailAddress).first()
```

and then I use the userID variable in my create object like this:

```
    newReading = Reading(uid=userID, sid=123,readingTimestamp = readingTimestamp, readingLightValue=readingLightValue,
                         readingLightStatus=readingLightStatus, readingTemp1=readingTemp1, readingTemp2=readingTemp2,
                         readingHumidity=readingHumidity)
```

I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gnomecentral`.`reading`, CONSTRAINT `reading_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `user` (`uid`))') 'INSERT INTO reading (uid, sid, `readingTimestamp`, `readingLightValue`, `readingLightStatus`, `readingTemp1`, `readingTemp2`, `readingHumidity`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' ((10L,), 123, datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 14, 14, 48, 7, 684071), 43, '43', 43.0, 43.0, 43.0)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!
Craig

Comment: what is the value and type of `userID`?

Answer (score 0):

`userID` is not the uid you're looking for, but a SQLAlchemy result tuple. Do this instead:

```
userID = db.session.query(User.uid).filter(User.emailAddress == userEmailAddress).scalar()
```

A few extra things:

1. The `Reading.__init__` method is not necessary if you're just using it that way, `db.Model.__init__` already does the same:

   ```
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       for key, value in kwargs.items():
           setattribute(self, key, value)
   ```
2. If User->Reading is a one-to-many relationship wouldn't `userReading` be clearer as `userReadings`?
3. A common convention in Python is to name variables, methods and functions like_this instead of camelCased.

Comment: That fixed it thank you.  I'll be changing my one to manys to plurals like you suggested, but I am pretty happy with CamelCasing my variables :)

Answer (score 0):

.first() is returning a row containing a single value, not that single value. So you are trying to use a collection of values as the uid in your new object. You can see this in the error; there's a tuple where a number should be.

You can use .scalar() to take the first column in the first row, instead of .first().